# How to perform integration tests with cypress-react-selector in production?

Tags: reactjs, integration-testing, cypress, production-environment

I've searched a lot in SO and documentation sites, but nothing solved my issue.
We're using [cypress-react-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-react-selector) to test our React application at work, and it works great in local development.

The problem is that as soon as we go on production and the React components get minified, al the tests don't pass since the `cy.getReact()` method is not able to find the components.

For example, in local development I use to have this piece of code:

```
cy
  .getReact('Button', { props: { icon: 'myAwesomeIcon' } })
  .should(({ node }) => node ? node.click() : null);
```

but in production the `Button` component is minified (and with the React Development tools I find that it is simply called `d`).

How can I create a test that is capable to run both in local and production env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this issue (20 days ago) ["Component not found" because of not considered displayName](https://github.com/abhinaba-ghosh/cypress-react-selector/issues/209), you can fix it by adding a `displayName`

> Previously, the used resq dependency did not consider the displayName as it's done in the React Dev Tools.
> The result was that, it was not possible to find components by their name, **if their name is minified**, even if they had a displayName.
>
> I've provided a fix for that, which has now been merged and released in resq version 1.10.1.
>
> Can you please update cypress-react-selector to use the new resq version, so that displayName is also considered here?

> Thanks @jens-duttke , it is available in the current version.

For a functional component,

```js
const Button = (props) => { ... }

Button.displayName = 'Button'
```

For a class component

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  static displayName = 'Button';
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However this would imply adding some custom logic for the testing phase, which is in first place considered bad practice (but I could not consider this problem this time); the real problem is that my application depends on components exposed by libraries not directly written by us, so I can't add the `displayName` everywhere. I'm afraid that this is not a usable solution for my case :(

Comment: Indeed, nevertheless it's going to benefit someone. I guess the rock has got you in the hard place - if you want to test E2E (minified), you will have to figure out Cypress code without the plugin.

Comment: displayName is mentioned as a best practice for debugging. My perspective is that it's minimal cost and pragmatic.

Comment: ***libraries not directly written by us*** - not really the focus of your tests?

Comment: I'll give it a try and then I'll come back to you. Let's try if I can manage it.
Thanks for now